# Getting facebook feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there the way to get facebook user's feed without special facebook permission?
We used to have an opportunity to get that through API. Unfortunately, we no longer can use it.

> As of October 6th, 2015, this endpoint is no longer available.

I also tried to get posts, using phantomjs. But it takes a lot of time and it kinda "weird" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the user timeline with `/me/posts` and the `user_posts` permission, but there is no way to get the feed anymore. Scraping is not allowed, so using phantomjs is out of the question.